# Best way to create a new List with a simple string and List<string> as default values?

Tags: c#

I'm looking to create a new `List<string>` in C# with 2 default values :
A simple `string` and a `List<string>`

My objective it's to create a new List who concat my string var and my List var

This is my current way and i'm looking for a better way :

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string SimpleString { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListString { get; set; }

    public List<string> Example()
    {
        return new List<string> { SimpleString }.Concat(ListString).ToList();
    }
}
```

Do you have a better way to achieve that ?
My dream it's to use like this : `new List<string> { SimpleString, ListString };` but it's not possible

Regards

Comment: How you specific what is the better way?

Comment: @Aria with less method chaining call

Comment: Why do you think you should do it?

Comment: @Mohi i'm looking to get the more efficient way

Comment: Why your concern is using less `Cahin` use is better? in the other side use `IEnumerable` instead

Comment: @Aria i'm just looking for faster way to achieve that.
So if IEnumerable is the faster way, i'm taking that way :)

Comment: Yes I am sure `IEnumerable` is always better than `List` so look at the @Joel Coehoorn answer.

Comment: @Aria ok thank's !

Comment: Whether IEnumerable is faster depends on your definition of faster. IEnumerable **tends** to use less memory, because you only need to care about one item at a time, and it can be faster because it can save the overhead for copying the entire collection. But there are times when memory is not the bottleneck, or when the overhead for the iterator objects out-weighs the other wins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is work with `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `List<string>` It is a little more code, but this should perform much better than what you've been doing, at least in many common situations:

```
public IEnumerable<string> AsEnumerable()
{
    yield return SimpleString;
    foreach(string item in ListString) yield return item;
}
```

Then, if a consumer of the type *really* needs a list (hint: it's not as common as you might think. IEnumerable fills a LOT of those use cases and tends to perform better) they can append their own `.ToList()`:

```
var stringList = MyObject.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

But if I were going to do this, I might instead implement `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
public class TestClass : IEnumerable<string> 
{
    public string SimpleString { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListString { get; set; }


    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
       yield return SimpleString;
       foreach(string item in ListString) yield return item;
    }   
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Now I can use this directly in a `foreach` loop and I get the `ToList()` method for free from `System.Linq`. That is, all of the following work, without any additional code:

```
var stringList = MyObject.ToList();
var fooItems = MyObject.Where(s => s.Contains("foo"));
foreach(string s in MyObject) // ...
```

To me, this is worth it even if you hit a case where the IEnumerable option is slower, as long as it's not egregiously so.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it in one line? This is pretty efficient.

```
public List<string> ToList()
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    list.Add(SimpleString);
    list.AddRange(ListString);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<T>` constructor accepting `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var otherList = new List<string> { "foo" };
var list = new List<string>(otherList);
```

and then write your own version of `Append()` extension method supporting `List<T>`:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<T> Append<T>(this List<T> source, T value)
    {
        source.Add(value);

        return source;
    }
}
```

so in the end you'll have:

```
var otherList = new List<string> { "foo" };
var list = new List<string>(otherList).Append("bar");
```